# Find repeated sequences of different numbers

Tags: r

I have a data source which has repeated values at some unknown interval, to make things more complicated, the number of times the data is repeated might not be an integer. Here is a contrived example:

```
set.seed(1)
Values <- sample(1:10,10,replace=T)
Values
 [1]  3  4  6 10  3  9 10  7  7  1

CombinedValues <- c(Values,Values,Values[1:5])
 [1]  3  4  6 10  3  9 10  7  7  1  3  4  6 10  3  9 10  7  7  1  3  4  6 10  3
```

My question is, given only the vector `CombinedValues` what is the most efficient way of deriving the longest repeated "pattern" (aka `Values`) in an efficient way given that we do not know how long the repeated vector is? My Expected output is either the vector `Values` or something that describes the index of where the pattern is repeated.

Does an existing package already have this functionality?

**Clarification**

- The data source contains only the repeated sequence
- The pattern is repeated at least twice
- We also know that the data starts with the pattern.
- The pattern does not overlap. So the desired output is the longest
  non-overlapping pattern.

Comment: Please include a call to `set.seed` when providing random numbers.

Comment: Also, what is the expected output? 2?

Comment: Edited to have seed and expected output.

Comment: If "the number of times the data is repeated might not be an integer", does that mean that in `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1`, the pattern `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` is repeated 1.1 times? That's a bit vague to me.. Also, does the array only contain the repeated sequence, or can it also contain 'garbage'?
 Please provide some input-output examples.

Comment: It only contains the repeated sequence, and I agree that the first part is vague, let me think to see if I can clarify.

Comment: @Florian I have added some extra detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
Values <- sample(1:10,10,replace=T)
CombinedValues <- c(Values,Values,Values[1:5])

max_seq <- function(x)
{
  max_seq_len=0
  for(i in 1:floor(length(x)/2))
  {
   y = split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/i))
   lengths=sapply(y,length)
   if(length(unique(y[which(lengths==max(lengths))]))==1)
   {max_seq_len=i}
  }
  return(max_seq_len)
}

max_seq(CombinedValues)
```

This returns 10, and `CombinedValues[1:max_seq(CombinedValues)]` returns your array:

```
[1]  3  4  6 10  3  9 10  7  7  1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this works very nicely. I'll accept your answer and add my own hacky solution as another.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found was to use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package. I make the assumption that the pattern is at least a certain length and that the probability of getting a false positive match is low.

```
which(rollapply(CombinedValues, 4, FUN=function(x) all(x == Values[1:4])))
```

In this case, getting 4 matches is a row doesnt have that low of a probability of a false positive. However in data when I can increase 4 to 1000, this works nicely for a quick solution.