# How to flatten nested structure when reading delimited text file?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested

I have a delimited text file that looks like this:

```
AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.047|I|
ABP|3|F|.019|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|1.204|E|
ABP|2|F|.974|E|
ABP|3|F|1.025|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.048|I|
ABP|3|F|.041|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|5.487|E|
ABP|2|F|5.485|E|
ABP|3|F|5.484|E|
```

And I've been struggling to transform it -- using for loops, etc. -- so that the each ABV record is a row with the AAA record above it and all the ABV records below it attached so that it looks like this:

```
AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.047|I|ABP|3|F|.019|I|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|1.204|E|ABP|2|F|.974|E|ABP|3|F|1.025|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.048|I|ABP|3|F|.041|I|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|5.487|E|ABP|2|F|5.485|E|ABP|3|F|5.484|E|
```

But I cant seem to make it work. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If we count the number of fields delimited by `|` by row we can observe the following pattern:

```
(fields <- count.fields(textConnection(txt), sep = "|"))
[1] 11  7  6  6  6  7  6  6  6  7  6  6  6 11  7  6  6  6  7  6  6  6  7  6  6  6
```

Assuming that the pattern holds across your data, we can use the following to concatenate the lines:

```
text <- readLines(textConnection(txt))

l1 <- fields == 11L
l2 <- fields == 7L
l3 <- fields == 6L

l2_id = cumsum(l2)

paste0(unlist(Map(paste, text[l1], split(text[l2], cumsum(l1)[l2]), sep = "")), tapply(text[l3], l2_id[l3], paste, collapse = ""))

[1] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.047|I|ABP|3|F|.019|I|"  
[2] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|"            
[3] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|1.204|E|ABP|2|F|.974|E|ABP|3|F|1.025|E|" 
[4] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.048|I|ABP|3|F|.041|I|"  
[5] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|"            
[6] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|5.487|E|ABP|2|F|5.485|E|ABP|3|F|5.484|E|"
```

Data:

```
txt <- "AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.047|I|
ABP|3|F|.019|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|1.204|E|
ABP|2|F|.974|E|
ABP|3|F|1.025|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.048|I|
ABP|3|F|.041|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|5.487|E|
ABP|2|F|5.485|E|
ABP|3|F|5.484|E|"
```

Comment: And for testing the regularity of sequence assumption [max_seq @florian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416877/find-repeated-sequences-of-different-numbers), of `(fields` is 13. This is a great approach. Could you expand a little on `l2_id = cumsum(l2)`?

Comment: @Chris - sure, it's just a method to assign a unique id to each run of values when a `7` is encountered, i.e. `c(11, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6)` would become `c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)`.

Comment: What indicates the choice of `l2` for id'ing as against `l1` (or l3) that is start for max_seq(), or is it simply 'derive an index' and I am mistakenly seeing a relationship between your's above and max_seq as one says how long and the other says what sequence, but we often seen `cumsum` used to derive indices...Said as much as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```r
library(stringr)
library(zoo)

txt <- 
"AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.047|I|
ABP|3|F|.019|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|1.204|E|
ABP|2|F|.974|E|
ABP|3|F|1.025|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.048|I|
ABP|3|F|.041|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|5.487|E|
ABP|2|F|5.485|E|
ABP|3|F|5.484|E|
"

txt <- str_replace_all(txt,regex("\n(?=ABP)"),"")

l <- setdiff(str_split_1(txt,"\n"),"")

aaa <- str_match(l,"^AAA.*") |> na.locf()
abv <- str_match(l,"^ABV.*")

i <- !is.na(abv)

l2 <- paste( aaa[i], abv[i], sep="" )

l3 <- paste(l2,collapse="\n")
cat(l3,"\n")

# save it to a file
cat(l3,"\n", file="outfile.txt")
```

Output:

```
AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.047|I|ABP|3|F|.019|I|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|1.204|E|ABP|2|F|.974|E|ABP|3|F|1.025|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.048|I|ABP|3|F|.041|I|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|5.487|E|ABP|2|F|5.485|E|ABP|3|F|5.484|E|
```

In short it does this:

- Remove newline before `ABP`
- Create a vector of same size with `AAA` line copied to next line until a new `AAA` shows up
- Get the `ABV` lines (that now contain `ABP`s also)
- Connect list of AAA strings with the list of ABV strings
- Put it all back together into a file

Answer (score 0):

First, use `grep` to find the "AAA" positions (likely faster in bash), then `scan` while skipping, count "ABV"s, and attach the header. Finally, `unlist`.

```
> pos <- system('cat foo.txt | grep -n -o AAA foo.txt | cut -d: -f1', intern=TRUE)
> # pos <- grep('AAA', readLines('foo.txt'))  ## alternatively just using R
> lapply(seq_along(pos), \(i) {
+   .skip <- (as.numeric(pos) - 1L)[i]
+   .nmax <- as.numeric(pos[i + 1L]) - .skip - 1L
+   r <- scan('foo.txt', what=character(), skip=.skip, nmax=.nmax, qui=T)
+   len <- sum(grepl('ABV', r))
+   sapply((seq_len(len) - 1L)*4L, \(j) 
+          paste(r[1], paste(r[2:5 + j], collapse=''), sep=''))
+ }) |> unlist()
 [1] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.047|I|ABP|3|F|.019|I|"  
 [2] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|"            
 [3] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|ABP|1|F|1.204|E|ABP|2|F|.974|E|ABP|3|F|1.025|E|" 
 [4] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.048|I|ABP|3|F|.041|I|"  
 [5] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|"            
 [6] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|5.487|E|ABP|2|F|5.485|E|ABP|3|F|5.484|E|"
 [7] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-2|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|5.487|E|ABP|2|F|5.485|E|ABP|3|F|5.484|E|"
 [8] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|.051|I|ABP|2|F|.048|I|ABP|3|F|.041|I|"  
 [9] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|"            
[10] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASHWW-2|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|0|E|ABP|2|F|0|E|ABP|3|F|0|E|"            
[11] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|5.487|E|ABP|2|F|5.485|E|ABP|3|F|5.484|E|"
[12] "AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|ABV|E_ASLVW-2|20161117|RF|16|20180105|ABP|1|F|5.487|E|ABP|2|F|5.485|E|ABP|3|F|5.484|E|"
```

Assuming entries start with "AAA" and sub-entries are of length 4. This can be adapted as needed.

---

*Data:*

```
AAA|C0421002|D|20180102091621|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|301873|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.047|I|
ABP|3|F|.019|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161113|RF|16|20171229|
ABP|1|F|1.204|E|
ABP|2|F|.974|E|
ABP|3|F|1.025|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.048|I|
ABP|3|F|.041|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|5.487|E|
ABP|2|F|5.485|E|
ABP|3|F|5.484|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-2|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|5.487|E|
ABP|2|F|5.485|E|
ABP|3|F|5.484|E|
AAA|C0421002|D|20180108092341|CD|UKDC|PB|PORTAL|302513|OPER|
ABV|E_ABERDARE|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|.051|I|
ABP|2|F|.048|I|
ABP|3|F|.041|I|
ABV|E_ASHWW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASHWW-2|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|0|E|
ABP|2|F|0|E|
ABP|3|F|0|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-1|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|5.487|E|
ABP|2|F|5.485|E|
ABP|3|F|5.484|E|
ABV|E_ASLVW-2|20161117|RF|16|20180105|
ABP|1|F|5.487|E|
ABP|2|F|5.485|E|
ABP|3|F|5.484|E|
```